# Laplace transform and inverse $\coth$ function

Tags: laplace-transform

What is laplace inverse of $\coth{\pi s/2w}$.Laplace transform of coth function.and how to evaluate it.I tried but unable to get the correct solution.

Comment: Laplace transform of inverse coth, or inverse Laplace transform of coth?

Answer (score 2):

Note that, for every $s\gt0$,
$$\coth(\pi s/2w)=\frac{1+\mathrm e^{-\pi s/w}}{1-\mathrm e^{-\pi s/w}}=(1+\mathrm e^{-\pi s/w})\sum_{n\geqslant0}\mathrm e^{-n\pi s/w}=1+2\sum_{n\geqslant1}\mathrm e^{-n\pi s/w}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-sx}\mathrm d\mu(x),
$$
where $\mu$ denotes the (discrete) measure
$$
\mu=\delta_0+2\sum_{n\geqslant1}\delta_{n\pi/w}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, Did, I misunderstood your notation and hence what you were doing.  (+1)